# Set email as an alias for username in Cognito is disabled in the GUI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want to set email as an alias for username for a user pool in Cognito. I found out that this was possible from the Cognito docs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html#user-pool-settings-aliases-settings-option-1

I can see the option in the GUI under general `settings > attributes`

[image: AWS Cognito GUI]

But the interface is disabled. I am `admin` and `AmazonCognitoPowerUser` in aws.

How can I add email as an alias for username?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the user pool has been created, AWS does not allow you to change this setting. You would have to create a new user pool and deal with migrating any existing users over. Yes, it is very annoying.

Comment: I can understand why they have this set. What is extremely frustrating is if you use Amplify CLI to create & integrate your User Pools, etc, where they don't provide the option to set aliases.